# Custom UIView subclass add nib subview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, xib, nib

I have a custom `UIView` subclass let's call it `CustomViewA` which I init with `initWithFrame:` and add some UIViews programatically (like a UILabel and so on). Now there is need for another view to be added to `CustomViewA` so I created a `nib` which I lay out some GUI elements inside (one being a `UISegmentedControl`)

Now I'm having some issues on how to correctly add this nib as a subview to `CustomViewA`. Do I need to create .h/.m files for the nib? I want CustomViewA to receive the actions when the segmented control changes values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was happening. The nib that I added to `CustomViewA` was added outside `CustomViewA`s frame. So apparently when a subview is outside the superview's frame it will not intercept touches.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNibName" owner:self options:nil];
[self.view addSubview:self.nibView];
```

In the nib, make sure that the File Owner's class is set to the view controller you are adding it to.

You can add properties and `IBActions` like normal from the nib as well.

Comment: I'm not adding the nib to a viewcontroller. I'm adding it to another UIView (`CustomViewA`). But maybe that doesn't matter? Also where do you set self.nibView ?

Comment: If you're adding it to another UIView, have that CustomViewA's view controller add the nib to CustomViewA

Comment: Also, I got self.nibView from an outlet set in the nib

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using another superview ? And just use `nibView` when referring to `view` ?

Answer (score 1):

**Do I need to create .h/.m files for the nib?**

No, you needn't.

**How to receive the actions when the segmented control changes values ?**

You can set a tag number for segmented control in your xib, it should be unique in all the subviews of the view in your xib.

You can get the segmented control with the code. `UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)[view viewWithTag:1024];`, once you get the segmented control, you can add an action with the code `[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Edit: **How to get the root view of xib?**

Use the code below:

`UIView *rootView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourXibName" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];`

Comment: Can I not add an action through the interface builder and defining an (IBAction) in my `CustomViewA` I've tried doing that connecting it to the segmented control but notthing happens when I tap the segmented control?

Comment: @PeterWarbo How did you load the xib ? Did you set the owner of xib when loading it ? If you add an action through IB and defining an (IBAction) in CustomViewA, you should load the xib using `UIView *rootView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourXibName" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];`.

Comment: Yes I loaded it like you described... the view is displayed properly on the screen but NOTHING happens when I tap on the segmented control. And in interface builder it says it's connected to UIControlEventValueChanged for my action...

Comment: @PeterWarbo Did you set the Class of file's owner as `CustomViewA` ?

Comment: yep... how can I debug this?

Comment: I just tried adding a `UIButton` to the nib and I'm receiving the action perfectly. This is really super strange why nothing is happening from the `UISegmentedControl`